# Is there a way to find time taken to run a particular function/operation

Tags: r

Is there a way to find to see what is the time taken to perform certain operation in R. I know we can use system start time and end time. But is there another way to do this. Something like `timetaken(fun(3,4))`

for example

```
fun <- function(x,y){
c = x + y
return(c)
}

fun(3,4)
7
```

Comment: `system.time(fun(3, 4))` is simplest, without using extra packages.

Comment: Thanks.... May i know what is ````user  system elapsed```` please

Comment: I noticed one thing, When I run this all time for the same operation. I get different time. Why?

Comment: Because time is variable. Your computer is complicated, and doing lots of things at any given time. You can use `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()` to run things multiple times and see statistics of the run time distribution.